# elastic search suggester filter

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

I am implementing suggester filter for search operation using elastic search API.

I have encountered problem like I can do search base in `prefix search`  only, but I cant do with middle word.

I had tried below example :

```
PUT / bls {
  "mappings": {
    "bl": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "name_suggest": {
          "type": "completion",
          "context": {
            "store": {
              "type": "category"
            },
            "status": {
              "type": "category"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
 POST / bls / bl / 1 {
   "name": "LG 32LN5110 32 inches LED TV",
   "name_suggest": {
     "input": ["sony 32LN5110 32 inches LED TV"],
     "context": {
       "store": [
         44,
         45
       ],
       "status": "Active"
     }
   }
 }

 POST / bls / _suggest ? pretty {
   "name_suggest": {
     "text": "sony",
     "completion": {
       "field": "name_suggest",
       "context": {
         "store": "44",
         "status": "Active"
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

I got result with above query but I cant do search with below query :

```
 POST / bls / _suggest ? pretty {
   "name_suggest": {
     "text": "LED",
     "completion": {
       "field": "name_suggest",
       "context": {
         "store": "44",
         "status": "Active"
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

and this above query display results as below :

```
{
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "name_suggest": [{
    "text": "LED",
    "offset": 0,
    "length": 3,
    "options": []
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The String type are indexed by default. So even without specifying the type they are indexed with Default Analyzer if no specific analyzer was specified.

For your case, you must specify the

> `index: analyzed` for name_suggest property

Such that an Anayzer containing whitespace analyzer is used, which will tokenize all the words in your input field. And hence can search anywhere across the text.